# Is there any way to use &nbsp; in component Trans of react-i18next?

Tags: javascript, react-i18next

I have an message `Oops. The link no longer works for some&nbsp;reason` with `&nbsp;`. I try to show it like that:

```
<Trans i18nKey='registration.invalid.inventation.title' components={renderedTags} />
```

`renderedTags` is an object:

```
renderedTags = {
  br: <br />,
  b: <b />,
  strong: <strong />,
  i: <i />,
  p: <p />,
  a: <a />,
  span: <span />,
};
```

But result of this on the page is `Oops. The link no longer works for some&nbsp;reason`. So `&nbsp;` didn`t converted

I know that there is a prop `shouldUnescape`, but if I use it non breakable space become regular space and words shows on different lines

Is there any way to use `&nbsp;` as an non breakable space with `Trans` component?

Answer (score 0):

You can have HTML entities such as `&nbsp;` work with the `Trans` component by adding another attribute to your `renderedTags` to be something similar to this. Just make sure you have the `nbsp` attribute within your translation as well. Also, be sure to never use this on user input, as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` [is vulnerable to XSS attacks](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html).

```
renderedTags = {
  nbsp: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '&nbsp;'}}></div>
  ...}
```